# How to associate newly created entities JPA / Spring

Tags: jpa

I have two different entities, an application user and a post. These are mapped in a onetomany / manytoone relationship.
When I create a new post, I would like the user that created the post to be associated with it.
Currently, I am trying the following:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/api/users/posts")
    @ResponseBody
    Post newPost (@RequestBody Post newPost) {
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = applicationUserRepository.findByUsername(newPost.getUsername());
        newPost.setUser(applicationUser);
        applicationUser.addPost(newPost);
        applicationUserRepository.save(applicationUser);
        return this.postRepository.save(newPost);
    }
```

The application user looks like the following:

```java
@Entity
public class ApplicationUser {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String username;

  ...

  @OneToMany(
      cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      orphanRemoval = true
  )
  @JsonManagedReference
  private Set<Post> posts;

  ...
```

and the post:

```java
@Entity
public class Post {

  private @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn
  @JsonBackReference
  private ApplicationUser user;

  private String username;

  ...
```

Currently, the post is created, but there is no association between the application user and post.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try out the below approach :

In your ApplicationUser entity modify the code like below

```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
  private Set<Post> posts;
```

And post entity like below

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private ApplicationUser user;
```

Am assuming your post entity has a foreign key with name 'user_id' which links to 'id' of application user.
Let me know if it works for you

Comment: This worked for me, I had to add   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user") and @JoinColumn(name = "user_id").